# Magento 2 - validate shipping address before moving to payment page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, onepage-checkout, shipping-address

I am trying to do a custom check for the pin code associated with the selected shipping address in the checkout shipping step.

When a person clicks 'Next' I want to do a custom check whether the delivery for that pin code is available or not.

Currently I have tried every possible way of using JavaScript or jQuery click events to trigger on the next button click, but nothing worked.

As far as I noticed, Magento does an internal REST API call to the shipping information endpoint and after that it goes to the payment and billing section.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

When the address-details are changed the event checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method is fired.
It will help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: i have tried with checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping and controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_save_shipping events but none worked. I had setup logger in those observer but no events were recoded.

Comment: did you got solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Use this checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method event in your etc/events.xml and then do your task inside events.
You can use Below observer code

```
<?php
namespace Playing\HelloWorld\Observer;
class ChangeDisplayText implements Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
 {
  $displayText = $observer->getData();  

  return $this;
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, You are right @ranjo